# Cant get image to display in subpage: HTML

Tags: html

Alright, so I have been attempting to get an image to display in one of my subpages in HTML. I am sure that this is a very simple and stupid issue in regards to how I am referencing the image in the code. The image file is called crab.jpg and it is inside the pics folder which is all contained in the Websites folder. I have no problems with similar code displaying images within the index file which is the main page for the website.

```
<img src="Websites/pics/crab.jpg"
width="400"
height="400"/>
```

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, unless it's in a subfolder. But try adding `/`
before the `Websites`

if that doesn't work try `../`

and if that doesn't work try `../../`